What causes Nepenthes gracilis leaves and pitchers to turn red?
In Borneo, I normally see Nepenthes gracilis with green leaves and pitchers that are mostly green. However, I found one plant with red leaves and red pitchers:

Context (red plant is at bottom right of photograph):

What could be the causes of the red coloration? Could it be due to environmental factors such as soil nutrients? All plants in the picture above are exposed to full sunlight.
